# ReactJS API. Вытащить из json блок значении

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Хочу вытащить данные эти в `li`, которых выделил в красном квадрате (см.картинку-1, ниже представлен код):

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

export default class Bitcoin extends React.Component {

state = {
    bitcoins: []
}

componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=0`)
        .then(res => {
            const bitcoins = res.data
            this.setState({ bitcoins })
        })
}

bitcoinView() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value
    document.getElementById("conclusion").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x
}

render() {
    return(
        <div>
            {   <select id="mySelect" onChange={this.bitcoinView}>
                    { this.state.bitcoins.map((bitcoin) => (
                        <option value={bitcoin.symbol}> {bitcoin.name} - {bitcoin.price_usd}$  </option> ) )
                    }
                </select>
            }
            <p id="conclusion"></p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Картинка-1:
[image: блок значении, которую хочу вытащить в "li"]

P.S: Вывод хочу чтобы был таков (см.картинку-2), плюс еще остальные данные как выше писал и показал в картинке-1: в "option" выбираю определенный биткоин, а там именно его блока данные выходят в "li"

Пример:

Картинка-2
[image: То что получилось у меня]

Answer (score 1):

`React` использует свой `ShadowDom` и **только при его изменении**(с помощью `setState()`) **вносит их** в реальный `DOM`. Когда вы мутируете `DOM` (`document.getElementById...`) напрямую, реакт не будет знать об этом, и его дальнейшее поведение **будет не предсказуемым**. Есть практика сохранения ссылки на `dom node` через свойство `ref`, но это является *"Bad practice"*, и нужно стараться этого избегать.

В Вашем случае можно просто завести новое *поле в стейте*, которое будет *хранить номер* выделенной опции

```
state = {
    bitcoins: [],
    bitcoinSelected: 0
}
```

А в функции `bitcoinView` просто его менять(`e.id` *не точное значение*, нужно прокинуть `id` в функцию, но думаю *суть понятна*)

```
bitcoinView(e) {
    this.setState({
       ...this.state,
       bitcoinSelected: e.id
    })
}
```

И ренедерить соответственно(и небольшая проверка, если наш массив с данными еще не пришел - ничего не отображать)

```
<p id="conclusion">
   {this.state.bitcoins && this.state.bitcoins[this.state.bitcoinSelected].symbol}
</p>
```

PS не забывайте давать *уникальные ключи* динамически генерируемым элементам

```
{ this.state.bitcoins.map((bitcoin, i) => (
                        <option key={i} value={bitcoin.symbol}> {bitcoin.name} - {bitcoin.price_usd}$  </option> ) )
                    }
```